# How to add my action to standard edit tableView button iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have UITableViewController with navigation bar. In viewDidLoad I added edit button:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

How can I show dialog before edit mode enabled? In what place can I do it?

Comment: You can use delegate methods after setting your controller delegate of UITableView. Delegate methods are mentioned here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the method 
`- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated`
 This method will be called when you click on edit button. Now you can put your functionality inside this method.